# Grouping data from 2 arrays by a unique key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

New to rails and struggling a bit!! HELP

So I have 2 arrays(one for employee work details, and another for employee personal details), both containing a unique corresponding key(employee code) that ties the information together.

How would one store both these arrays into a hash, by employee code, so work details and personal details need to be tied together on the unique key.

I have tried all sorts of methods of sorting, but nothing seems to want to do the trick.

Basically in the end I want to be able to print out a list of all the employees, displaying all their details together.

EMPLOYEE: Name: John Key: 001 etc etc
DETAILS: Title: Manager Key 001 etc etc

EMPLOYEE: Name: Sally Key: 002 etc etc
DETAILS: Title: Admin Key 002 etc etc

and so forth..

Comment: Are the two objects you have Arrays, or Hashes?  How are you able to identify the unique key in an Array?  It sounds more like they are Hashes.  Please can you post some example data structures for us to work with?

Answer (score 0):

assuming "employees" is an array of Employee objects, and "details" is an array of Detail objects...

```
employees.map do |employee|
  {
    :employee => employee, :details => details.select { |detail| detail.key == employee.key }
  }
end
```

BTW Is there some reason you don't have associations between employee and details? (you tagged this as Rails...)

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee = Struct.new(:id, :name)
Detail = Struct.new(:id, :title)

employees = [ Employee.new(1, "John"), Employee.new(2, "Sally") ]
details   = [ Detail.new(2, "Admin"), Detail.new(1, "Manager") ]

Hash[
  employees.map do |employee|
    detail = details.find { |d| d.id == employee.id }
    [ employee.id, { :employee => employee, :detail => detail } ]
  end
]
```

Or if you know all ids will exist in both arrays:

```
Hash[
  employees.sort_by { |e| e.id }.zip(details.sort_by { |d| d.id }).map do |e,d|
    [ e.id, { :employee => e, :detail => d } ]
  end
]
```

Gives:

```
{
  1 => {
    :employee => #<struct Employee id=1, name="John">,
    :details  => #<struct Detail id=1, title="Manager">
  },
  2 => {
    :employee => #<struct Employee id=2, name="Sally">,
    :details  => #<struct Detail id=2, title="Admin">
  }
}
```